# Can ANT save my day??? over JBoss ON?

Tags: java, ant

My firm been looking at JBoss on for building java web systems and pushing them out to servers.  but I was just thinking can it all be done with ANT??  I think so but I am looking for some 3rd parties to tell me then I am not going crazy and ANT can save my day.

We need the following:

- Something that can build a java program (web/non-web) into classes, JARS and WARS
- Push the JARS and WAR onto a server (FTP,SFTP)

Comment: use maven http://maven.apache.org/

Comment: You can use ant or maven. Test both and made your decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ant to perfrom a sourcecode checkout. Build compile and precompile java and jasper jsp files. Run the unittests and package the app as a war file and upload it to a server. So yes this is possible.

Comment: can you please give me some examples

Comment: Examples on scp: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html. An example on making a war file: http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/how-to-create-a-war-file-using-ant/. Just do some online research and play around with ant and maven, see what feels best for your project/setup.